# Defining typescript generics with type safety

Tags: generics, typescript

Can you define generics with safe types, as you can with c#?

E.g.

```
public bool Foo<T>() where T : struct { /* */ }
```

Typescript now has generics, but can I perform a similar action?

Thanks.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Ok it seems you can do this:

```
Foo<T extends IBar>() { /* */ }
```

And that seems to make all calls require the T to implement `IBar`.

Comment: +1 - spot on. This is taken from the Java implementation of generics - the `extends` keyword is used to constrain to either an interface or a class.

Comment: But it seems it does not enforce anything yet.

Comment: Note that if you want to constrain by interfaces, you use the `extends` keyword rather than the `implements` on. For example `Foo<T extends IBar>`.

Comment: @Tarion, [it seems to work for me](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=interface%20IFoo%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%09foo%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Bar%3CT%20extends%20IFoo%3E%0D%0A%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20bad%3A%20Bar%3Cstring%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20good%3A%20Bar%3C%7Bfoo%3Astring%7D%3E%3B%0D%0A)

Comment: Note that it's not required for a type to "implement" the IBar interface, it must merely be compatible with it.

Comment: @Panu I would think that in typescript this is self-explanatory, considering to what it compiles...

Comment: No its a valid point. C# would force implementation, while TS just forces compatibility. It's the same with all interfaces in TS though.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create an extra class/interface, you can, for example, do the following:

`Foo<T extends{ id: string | number }>`